# Perform a translation / rotation of a CMSampleBuffer OpenGL Swift

Tags: ios, swift, opengl-es, frame, cmsamplebuffer

I'm trying to read an AVAsset and in every frame of the asset, do a translation or a rotation operation, using the GPU.

From my researches, I found out a way to convert a CMSampleBuffer to a GPU texture. I'm using the following method to do it:

```
func texture(fromBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer) -> GLuint {
        var texture : GLuint = 0
        glGenTextures(1, &texture)
        glBindTexture(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), texture)
        glTexParameteri(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER), GL_LINEAR)
        glTexParameteri(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER), GL_LINEAR)
        glTexParameteri(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S), GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
        glTexParameteri(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T), GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)

        if let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) {
            CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
            let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer)
            let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer)
            glTexImage2D(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), 0, GL_RGBA, GLsizei(width), GLsizei(height), 0, GLenum(GL_BGRA), GLenum(GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE), CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer))
            CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
        }
        return texture
}
```

Now I need to do my desired operations with this texture, but this is the point I'm stuck. From a Objc example, I translated a function that receive as a param a texture and return a CGImage.

Here's the method:

```
func processTexture(_ texture: GLuint, width: Int, height: Int) -> CGImage? {
        var newImage : CGImage?
        var frameBuffer : GLuint = 0

        glGenFramebuffers(1, &frameBuffer)
        glBindFramebuffer(GLenum(GL_FRAMEBUFFER), frameBuffer)

        var colorRenderbuffer : GLuint = 0


        glGenRenderbuffers(1, &colorRenderbuffer)
        glBindRenderbuffer(GLenum(GL_RENDERBUFFER), colorRenderbuffer)
        glRenderbufferStorage(GLenum(GL_RENDERBUFFER), GLenum(GL_RGBA8_OES), GLsizei(width), GLsizei(height))
        glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GLenum(GL_FRAMEBUFFER), GLenum(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0), GLenum(GL_RENDERBUFFER), colorRenderbuffer)

        let status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GLenum(GL_FRAMEBUFFER))
        if status != GLenum(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
            print("ERROR")
        } else {
            glViewport(0, 0, GLsizei(width), GLsizei(height))
            glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
            glClear(GLbitfield(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT))

            let data = UnsafeMutablePointer<Data>.allocate(capacity: width * height * 4)

            glReadPixels(0, 0, GLsizei(width), GLsizei(height), GLenum(GL_RGBA), GLenum(GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE), data)

            let cgDataProviderReleaseDataCallback: CGDataProviderReleaseDataCallback = { (info: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?, data: UnsafeRawPointer, size: Int) -> () in
                return
            }

            if let dataProvider = CGDataProvider(dataInfo: nil, data: data, size: width * height * 4, releaseData: cgDataProviderReleaseDataCallback) {
                let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
                newImage = CGImage(width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: 8, bitsPerPixel: 32, bytesPerRow: width * 4, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo:  .byteOrder32Big, provider: dataProvider, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true, intent: .defaultIntent)
            }
        }
        return newImage
    }
```

But I can't find where I can perform the operations of translation and rotation on this code, or how could I do it.

Glad if anyone that already worked with OpenGL on iOS, could give me a help with it or even tell me where I can find examples of such operations.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a quad (two triangles) with your texture on it. You apply transformations (rotation, translation, scale, etc) to that quad. Take a look on GPUImage library source code.

Comment: I'll take a look on it. Thanks for the tip.